Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'clr._internal.CLRMetatype'>
I am very new to CUDA...
I have written a module in .Net 6.0 and I need to scale up the execution time utilizing CUDA in a Ubuntu machine. The method I need to call is defined as:
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
     public static string Calc(double a, double b, string c)
     {
         return "something";
     }
  }
}

using python in the ubuntu machine I have written the following code:
import os
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime
# Get the current working directory
current_directory = os.getcwd()
rt = get_coreclr(runtime_config = os.path.join(current_directory, r"runtimeConfig.json"))
set_runtime(rt)
import clr  # Import the pythonnet module

# Import the .NET namespace
from MyNamespace import MyClass

import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda

# function optimized to run on gpu
@jit(target_backend='cuda' ,nopython=True) 
def calculate_distances_kernel(x, y, c):  
    result = MyClass.Calc(x, y, c)
    return result


item = calculate_distances_kernel(0, 0, "abc")

When I try to execute it get this:
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'MyClass': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'clr._internal.CLRMetatype'>

Is there a way to define MyClass in such a way so Numba understands it?

The one word answer is no.

You're asking numba to take .net code and convert it to run on the GPU.  It doesn't know how to do that.  It has a python fallback mode, but when you specify nopython, then it cannot do the JIT compile.  I think you're unlikely to have any luck with this zero-effort method to get a numba kernel created, and you will likely need to write some numba code yourself, among other things, in order to perform the equivalent of  your .net Calc function.  Also, by definition, a numba cuda kernel cannot  return a value.
